# Best time to buy and sell stocks when allowing consecutive buys or sells

Tags: algorithm

### Problem

You're given the *n* stock prices for *n* days. Output the maximum profit you can reach by trading stocks. You can only trade at most once a day: on each day you can choose to either buy a single stock, or sell a single stock (if you have one), or give up the trade for that day and do nothing.

#### Example 1:

Given `a = [1,2,10,9]`, return `16`

**Explanation:**

You can buy on day 1 and 2 and sell on day 3 and 4.

Profit: -1-2+10+9 = 16

#### Example 2:

Given `a = [9,5,9,10,5]`, return `5`

**Explanation:**

You can buy on day 2 and sell on day 4.

Profit: -5 + 10 = 5

### My analysis

The difficult part is that you can **engage in consecutive buys and/or sells**, meaning that once you posses a stock, you don't necessarily have to sell it before buying another one.

My idea is the following algorithm:

Start from the largest price, and then match the smallest price that occurs *before* that maximum price in the input array. After matching, remove these two prices from the array and keep repeating this process until you can find no more match. It seems like this algorithm works, but it costs *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time, which is not fast enough.

### Question

How could this be solved with a better time complexity, such as *O(nlogn)*?

Comment: Cool problem! I'm not sure what you mean by "engage in multiple transactions at the same time" - there is just (at most) one buy or sell per day, yes?

Comment: Not necessarily at most one transaction, there can be more than one transactions. Engage in multiple transactions at the same time means that you can buy another stock before you sell your previous bought stock.

Comment: This problem is different from the II, IV problems in that it can allow users to buy another new stock before selling their previous bought stock

Comment: Do we have an infinite supply of cash?

Comment: Yeah, you can buy any number of stocks before you sell them. But make sure you can finally sell them and make profits.

Comment: Note: I don't think your algorithm always works, for example with input [1 8 2 9]

Comment: Yeah, thanks for finding the counter example!

Answer (score 10):

We can model this as a min-cost circulation problem and solve it optimally with a specialized O(n log n)-time algorithm similar to your idea.

In the flow network, there is a node for each day and a node representing the market. There are two unit-capacity arcs for each day, one from the market with cost equal to the price that day, one to the market with cost equal to minus the price. There are arcs of zero cost and unbounded capacity that can move flow from each day (except the last) to the one after it. These represent holding stock.

Using `()` to represent nodes, `==>` to represent unbounded capacity arcs and `-->` to represent unit capacity arcs, and labeling the costs, your sample instance is

```
      0        0        0
 ()======>()======>()======>()
 ^\       ^\       ^\       ^\
1| |-1   2| |-2  10| |-10  9| |-9
  \v       \v       \v       \v
  (                            )
```

Technically it's possible in this reformulation to both buy and sell on the same day, but that's not a profitable move, so it doesn't matter.

Given a residual network, the theory (linear programming duality) says we're done if and only if there's no negative-cost simple cycle. The intuitive meaning of such cycles is exactly what you would expect: buying a share and selling it profitably later.

The algorithm works by successively eliminating all negative-cost simple cycles (profitable cycles from now on) on the first `k` days for `k` from `1` to `n`. In the base case `k = 1`, the first day alone is never profitable, so we can move along to the inductive step.

For the inductive step, we know that there are no profitable cycles in the first `k-1` days and want to extend that to `k`. If there is a profitable cycle in the first `k` days, it involves selling on day `k`. But what to buy? We can answer that question efficiently by maintaining a min-priority queue of our residual buying opportunities. We compare the day `k` price to the queue min, and if it's higher we do the deal, which involves popping the min and pushing the day `k` price, since from the point of view of the residual network, canceling our sale later looks the same as buying a share. Then we push the day `k` price regardless to represent the possibility of actually buying on day `k`.

We have to be careful here and prove that we didn't just introduce another profitable cycle. That's the reason to choose the min: we can't combine the new "selling" (actually canceling the buy) opportunity profitably with any of the residual buying opportunities, because the new selling price was not greater than any of those opportunities.

The finished algorithm is pretty simple. In Python:

```
import heapq


def trading_profit(prices):
    profit = 0
    queue = []
    for price in prices:
        if queue and queue[0] < price:
            profit += price - queue[0]
            heapq.heapreplace(queue, price)
        heapq.heappush(queue, price)
    return profit
```

Comment: I certainly miss something simple, but I don't understand Python well, and from your explanation I don't understand how it works for case ( 3 1 2 4 ), profit = 3

Comment: @Damien when it scans 2, it buys at 1 and sells at 2, booking profit 1. Then it scans 4 and "buys" at 2 (in problem terms, actually undoing the sale at 2, but that looks exactly the same from the flow point of view) and sells at 4, booking additional profit 2, plus 1 equals 3.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, great answer.

Comment: So, in the queue, in the first step, 2 replaces 1, I understood incorrectly that 1 and 2 were matched and that both disappear from the queue. I will need further thinking, looks great

Comment: @Damien yes, the queue evolves as [], [3], [1, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 4], where the missing 1 at the end can be interpreted as a purchase at 1 and the extra 4 as a sale at 4.

Comment: Impressive and yet so simple! Given the conditions at which `heappushpop` is executed, it can be `heapreplace`, which I find easier to understand. How should we interpret the fact that if the `if` block is executed, that `price` gets to be on the heap twice (a second time with `heappush`)?

Comment: Just realised that the price should indeed be pushed a second time: first time represents a possibility to annul a decision to sell at that price, and the second one represents a possibility to replace that null-operation with a buy at that price. I think this answer is a candidate for the bounty.

Comment: @trincot Yep, I'll change it to heapreplace.

Comment: Again, great answer. Bounty awarded. There was no competition ;-)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat How would you modify this approach if you had to limit how many stocks you can hold at a time? So, for example, if you had [1, 1, 3, 3] and your limit was 1 stock, then your maximum profit would only be 2 because you can't buy both 1's and sell them later.

Comment: @Norbert the short version is that you can change the unbounded capacity arcs (`===>`) to have bounded capacity. I'm not sure how well the specialized min circulation algorithm transfers over—that's worth a new question.

Answer (score 3):

This is an O(n²) algorithm. So in that sense it does not answer your question for something asymptotically faster, but as in a comment you learned that you're algorithm won't work, I believe it may be useful nonetheless.

I'd go for dynamic programming. Iterate over the days, and maintain a list where the index describes the number of stock you have, and the value is the best cash balance to arrive in that situation. So start with the list being `[0]`, i.e. a single entry indicating that you can have zero stock at balance zero.

For each day, you can buy, sell or skip. You can express all the together using something like this:

```
balance_new[i] = max(balance[i], balance[i-1] - quote, balance[i+1] + quote)
```

The first entry represents skip: you keep current stock and balance. The second entry represents buy: you gain one stock (from `i-1` to `i`) but reduce balance by the day's price. The third entry is a sell: you reduce stock by one but gain the current price to your balance.

The `balance_new` you get from this becomes the `balance` for the next day. And you'll need to take some care around the boundary of the list, where one of the expressions becomes invalid because it would index out of bounds. You can't get to zero stock with a buy operation. The requested maximum profit is `balance[0]` after you've processed all days. It represents the maximum balance that leaves you with no stock.

You have an outer loop iterating over n days. And an inner loop iterating over the potential number of stock you might possess at that point. That number grows linear in each iteration. If you want you can try to be clever and reduce the number of steps for the inner loop by one after you reached half the steps of the outer loop. That's because it never pays to acquire more stock than you can sell by the end. So the number of steps in the inner loop would go from something like one to something like n/2 then back down again, for a total of n²/4 + O(n) but that's still in O(n²) over all.

Comment: I thought it was fairly obvious that there is an O(n^2) solution. What seems interesting is if we can take advantage of price comparisons to somehow improve the time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:  My logic failed (for [9, 12, 1, 18, 17, 13, 1, 2, 10] gave 29 instead of 35)...

Here's the logic I came up with:

1. map arr a to arr of {value, day, and relation}.
2. set 1st relation to "smaller", and the following to "smaller"|"equal"|"bigger" compared to prev.
3. from start, find last consecutive "smaller"(and then "smaller"|"equal"), from there, find last consecutive "bigger", match (push to buy and sell arrays) and remove.
4. repeat from 2, until all not "bigger", or length<2.
5. you are left with buy and sell pairs in their respective arrays(which will yield the maximum profit).

Comment: Not sure about complexity notations, but I think it's N+2N+2(N-2)+2(N-4) - as long as N-x>1, so it's less than N^2

Comment: The task only asks for the maximum profit, not a pairing.

Comment: Gil'ad, to find the maximum profit you need to buy and sell, and as per the question, it works in pairs...

Comment: @iAmOren, N+(N-2)+(N-4)+(N-6)+...+4+2 = N/2(N/2 + 1) = O(N²).